# DiscordJS How To Edit Messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am using `discord.js v11.2.1` to edit messages, and I cannot simply figure out. I am trying to edit a message, from a different channel, and I am using `TextChannel` to `fetchMessage(id)` so I could edit.

```
new Discord().TextChannel.fetchMessage(message_id)
    .then(message => message.edit("new message"));
```

And my error is that `Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`. So what should I do?

Basically, I have a command which will send a message to another channel. And I want to use the command to edit the message from another channel.

Comment: It may be because you are creating a new instance of Discord().

Comment: Yes, it was because I was creating a new instance. Instead of passing on the Client instance to module.exports, I was instating a new one in a separate file, which was returning null.

Comment: I added it as an answer as we are not supposed to answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are creating a new instance of the bot, making it return null.